# Where should I place an app?

Tags: software-installation

Recent switcher from Mac here.

I use a programming app called Xojo that is downloaded from the authors website, not available on the software store. It comes as a folder with an executable in it. I can run the app by double clicking it but I don't know where to place the containing folder. At the moment, it's just in my downloads folder.

On the Mac, I would just drop the executable into the Applications folder. Is there a Linux equivalent?

Also the executable doesn't show up when I type in the dash and doesn't seem to have an icon (although icons for it are provided for it in the folder). How do I get it to show up in dash searches too?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not a duplicate. The references article doesn't suggest where to store downloaded applications? I presume leaving them in my downloads folder is not the most sensible place??

Comment: You don't put it in any folder, put it where you prefer and give the .desktop the file to run in the `exec` line. This is not mac OSX, it works differently. Once the .desktop is in the right folder, you will see the app in dash. I suggest you just put your apps folder in your /home and make the exec line point to the executable in that folder.